# How do I make my Java 7 OSX App draggable on toolbar only

Tags: java, macos, swing, java-7

By default a Java 7 application is only movable on Mac if you click near the top of the window (like on Windows), however if I set

```
toolbar.getRootPane().putClientProperty("apple.awt.draggableWindowBackground")
```

I can then move the window by dragging on the toolbar. Unfortunately because this property is applied to the rootpane, and then is just one rootpane for the frame that the whole applications is a part of the window moves whereever I drag on it, I only want to be able to drag on it in the toolbar.

The main part of my application is a JTable and I really don't want the window to be moved when I dragclick here because it causes lots of problems such as I can now no longer reorder by table columns by dragging the table headers because that just moves the whole window. How can I limit movement to either.

1. Only the JToolbar
2. Everywhere except the Jtable

whichever is easiest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, I used UnifiedToolbar from the [MacWidgets](http://code.google.com/p/macwidgets/) project with Java 6. Since moving to Java 7 and no longer using UnifiedToolbar I couldn't see a solution but delving into the code simply using WindowsDragger class works perfectly well

i.e.

```
new WindowsDragger(frame, toolbar);
new WindowsDragger(frame, statusbar)
```

In contrast the "apple.awt.draggableWindowBackground" option is only really useful if happy for the whole frame to be draggable.